# How can I tell if I have community, enterprise, or standard edition mysql?

Tags: mysql

We are in the process of upgrading our servers and I was asked about the version of mysql we have currently (as we would like to stick with the same type, just upgrade the version). I need to know which edition I have installed. Here's the information I got when I ran `SHOW VARIABLES;`

```
protocol_version    10
version 5.0.67
version_comment SUSE MySQL RPM
version_compile_machine x86_64
version_compile_os  suse-linux-gnu
```

EDIT I also found the license in the variables, which says GPL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the `version` and `version_comment` would have this information, and `STATUS` command would also show them combined in `Server version:`, e.g.

```
Server version:         5.0.67-standard MySQL Community Edition - Standard     (GPL)
```

However, you are using version that comes from [`SUSE RPM` repository](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/suse/); it's community edition.

You could check that with (shell, not SQL) command `rpm -q mysql`. The name of the package might actually contain `mysqlXX-community-release-...` to confirm that.

Comment: When I run `STATUS`, for version, I get: ` 5.0.67 SUSE MySQL RPM`. When I run `rpm -q mysql`, it just gives me `mysql-5.0.67-12.15`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just install it without any payment and contract you have community edition. If you have some contract with mysql or oracle, look into that papers and you should see it. More info about mysql editions can be found at https://www.mysql.com/products/

Comment: The thing is, the person that set this up is no longer at the company. I have no way of knowing if they paid for anything. When I did `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE  '%license%'`, it says GPL. Would this mean I have the community edition?

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same doubet.

```
mysql> show global variables like '%version%';
+-------------------------+----------------+
| Variable_name           | Value          |
+-------------------------+----------------+
| protocol_version        | 10             |
| version                 | 5.0.26         |
| version_comment         | SUSE MySQL RPM |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64         |
| version_compile_os      | suse-linux     |
+-------------------------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

It seems `license` variable answer our question:

```
mysql> show global variables like '%license%';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| license       | GPL   |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

In other environment that I know is enterprise, it show comercial.

```
mysql> show global variables like '%license%';
+---------------+------------+
| Variable_name | Value      |
+---------------+------------+
| license       | Commercial |
+---------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```